# Fork oil for Suzuki GSXR 155 Naked

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, suzuki, gsxr

I want to change the fork oil on a Suzuki GSXR155.

Which fork oil should I  use? The suspension is not working and the handlebar is vibrating while riding on speed brakers, off road drives.

Comment: What do you mean the "*suspension are not working*"? Are the forks bottomed out? Are they leaking oil? How old is your Suzuki?

Comment: What is a 'speed brakers'?